# Write-Host from an asynchronus event

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to write to console from an asynchronus event in powershell.

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 2000     
$timer.AutoReset = $false  
$timer.Enabled = $true

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier c4n4 -Action {Write-Host test}
```

This obviously works. But if i encapsulate the Write-Host action within a function. It doesnt anymore.

```
function myFunc{
  Write-Host test
}

$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 2000     
$timer.AutoReset = $false  
$timer.Enabled = $true

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier c4n4  -Action {myFunc}
```

So basically my question is. How do i write to console from an event within a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the function in the global scope:

```
function global:myFunc{
  Write-Host test
}
```